# Column type time, comes from server with date and does not display

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I have a column with type `TIME`.

When I look in the DB, everything looks fine, I have values like `09:05`.

BUT, when I get the info to my rails webpage, I get it like this:

```
<input class="form-control" id="workshop_request_start_time" name="workshop_request[start_time]" size="30" type="time" value="2000-01-01 09:05:00 +0200">
```

As you can see, it comes with date.

In the form I have:

```
<%= f.text_field :start_time, type: :time, class: "form-control" %>
```

Since I get the field with the date, chrome / edge browsers do not display anything.

How is it possible, and how to solve it?

Comment: You can use a `time_select` helper for time values.

Comment: You could do something like this - `<%= f.text_field :start_time, type: :time, value: @instance_variable.start_time.strftime("%H:%M"), class: "form-control" %>`

Comment: Please write it as an answer so I can mark it. Great answer! Thx.